# How to display a list of items both ungrouped and grouped. (ListView vs ExpandableListView)

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I'm trying to display a list of items (songs) in various forms dynamical selected by the user.  I'm using an [`ExpandableListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) to group by album, artist or year depending on the user's selection.  When the selection changes it automatically regroups the items.

What makes this more complicated is that the items are the result of a search which may still be in progress.  So there is a fairly strong coupling between the search thread class and the adaptor ([`BaseExpandableListAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseExpandableListAdapter.html)) so that the search can dynamically pump data into the groups and generate new groups over a period of up to two minutes.  This all is working fine.

My question is how do I switch to showing all tracks ungrouped.  There doesn't seem to be an option to display child items without a group item.  At the moment I've got round this by creating a single group "All items".  This doesn't look good on the UI.  I've tried setting it to expanded and visibility [`GONE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE) but that still leaves the group item in place, just blank. Are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

What about using both at the same time ListView and ExpandableListView, overlapping each other inside a relative layout ?

Then you may use something like this to switch from one to another

```
public void setListViewMode(boolean isExpandable){
    findViewById(R.id.my_expandable_listview).setVisibility(isExpandable ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    findViewById(R.id.my_normal_listview).setVisibility(!isExpandable ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
}
```

or another way (maybe more easy):

Have you tried to hide your view group inside

```
public View getGroupView(){

    ...

    convertView.setVisibility(isExpandable ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    return convertView;
}
```

or maybe:

```
getExpandableListView().setGroupIndicator(null);
```

Comment: Hmm that may be the way to go.  I'd need to both implement `ListAdapter` and `ExpandableListAdapter` in the same class. Do you know if there are any conflicts between the methods (any methods of the same prototype but requiring different implementations)?

Comment: I think you don't need both adapters in just one class, you may have two different adapters and two different listViews, each listView with its own adapter and then choose the listView you want to show with setListViewMode(..) As ExpandableListView extends ListView maybe you can figure out how to save some lines of code, but I am not sure whether it worth the effort

Comment: Yeah, there's the problem. This may be achievable with some heavy re-factoring.  The issue lies with the fact that the adaptor isn't representing a static dataset, but a (*potentially in-progress*) search.  Having two separate adaptor objects might make this a bit messy.

Comment: I guess you use AsyncTask for your data searching, if it is inside the adapter, move it out of it and inside onPostExecute refresh both adapters using adp.add(mydata), adp.notifyDataSetChanged(); (x2)

Comment: yes, its a nice idea, the trouble is the group element still displays, it's just blank (and not clickable).  Guess the ExpandableListView has a wrapper view which you have no control over.

Comment: try with getExpandableListView().setGroupIndicator(null);